# Expressing 'likeness' and using ku Verbs in the past tense

Tags: past

I'm trying to say "I drew an original character in the NEWGAME! style"

> 俺はオリギナル、カラクターを描いたNEWGAME!みたい

That is the way I formulated my sentence but it seems off; can someone help?

Comment: I think you should check the pronunciations of ギ and ジ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, fix some typo: オリギナル → [オリジナル](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B8%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB), カラクター → [キャラクター](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%A9%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC). And you don't need a comma between them.

Second, you are using ～みたい incorrectly. `noun + みたい` acts and conjugates like a [na-adjective](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/adjectives), and adjectives always comes *before* the modified noun.

After fixing these, you get:

> 俺はNEW GAME!みたいなオリジナルキャラクターを描いた。

To translate your sentence more literally, "in the art style of ～" can be rendered to ～の絵柄【えがら】で.

> 俺はNEW GAME!の絵柄でオリジナルキャラクターを描いた。

Additionally, you may need the polite form (描きました) instead, depending on where you are going to post this.

Comment: I see! So I have to treat みたい like an adjective; I didnt know that; thank you!

Comment: @user36606 If you're good at anime, you may find this "Xの絵柄でY" page interesting: http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2134737700907736201